Remove bold without selecting the data sheet
The code makes Excel "flicker" a lot since it first makes the data sheet visible then selects it. Once that is done it hides the sheet again as intended.
Is there a way to remove the "Bold" parts of the code without selecting the data sheet to make it visible?
I also want that the user is still in the active sheet and cell they were in before running the code. Right now it auto selects the last sheet in the workbook. I guess that is because the data sheet gets hidden.
I am running this macro in a userform.
Private Sub TextBox2_Change()
' decleration
    Dim row As Integer
    Dim wkb As Workbook
    row = 1

    ' sheet name where data is
    **Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Sheets("DataSheet").Visible = True
    Sheets("DataSheet").Select**

    ' search column A for match
    Do While Range("A" & row).Value <> ""

        ' disply content if match found
        If Range("A" & row).Value = TextBox2.Text Then

            ' display
            Label8.Caption = Range("A" & row).Value
            Label9.Caption = Range("B" & row).Value
            Label10.Caption = Range("C" & row).Value
            Label11.Caption = Range("D" & row).Value
            Label16.Caption = Range("E" & row).Value

            ' exit loop because match is found
            Exit Do

        End If

        ' next entry
        row = row + 1

    Loop

    ' no entry found
    If Range("A" & row).Value = "" Then
        Label8.Caption = "No match found"
        Label9.Caption = "No match found"
        Label10.Caption = "No match found"
        Label11.Caption = "No match found"
    End If
    
    **Sheets("DataSheet").Visible = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True**
End Sub


Add Sheets("DataSheet"). before every instance of Range.

^^^ see here for more info on avoiding Select in your code

@BigBen That seems to have done it, i cant believe i did not try that. Thank you! Im gonna try this and se if there is no errors in the data.

You might find Match is easier (and faster), and as noted above there's no need to Select anything
Private Sub TextBox2_Change()

    Dim m As varaint, ws As Worksheet
    
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("DataSheet")
    m = Application.Match(TextBox2.Text, ws.Columns("A"), 0) 'look for a match
    
    If Not IsError(m) Then 'm will be an error value if no match was made
        Label8.Caption = ws.Cells(m, "A").Value
        Label9.Caption = ws.Cells(m, "B").Value
        Label10.Caption = ws.Cells(m, "C").Value
        Label11.Caption = ws.Cells(m, "D").Value
        Label16.Caption = ws.Cells(m, "E").Value
    Else
        'no match
        Label8.Caption = "No match found"
        Label9.Caption = "No match found"
        Label10.Caption = "No match found"
        Label11.Caption = "No match found"
        'Label16?
    End If

End Sub

